# Удалить всё предложение в котором есть ссылка

Tags: php, строки, форматирование

Нужно решение, которое анализирует текст, находит предложение в котором присутствует ссылка/или просто слово определенно, и удаляет всё предложение. Т.е. предложение - это начало с большой буквы и заканчивается на символах окончания предложения - '.!?'
Вот пример. Есть текст:

```
"Привет, как дела? Пройди по ссылке, <a href="www.dot.com">нажав сюда</a> и твоя жизнь изменится!"
```

После обработки должна получиться строка "Привет, как дела?".

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Привет, как дела? Пройди по ссылке, <a href='www.dot.com'>нажав сюда</a> и твоя жизнь изменится!";

$sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[а-яА-Я])/i', $str); // разбиваем строку на массив по регулярному выражению (элементами массива будут являться предложения)

foreach($sentences as $key => &$sentence) {
    if (strpos($sentence, "<a") !== false) { // если в предложении содержится подстрока <a href=", удаляем такое предложение
        unset($sentences[$key]);
    }
}

$sentences = implode(' ', $sentences); // объединяем оставшиеся элементы массива в строку
print_r($sentences); // выводим
```

Comment: `<a class="myClass" href=` и уже ничего не заменяется(. Также существует `preg_replace_callback` в котором можно описать логику замены.

Comment: поправил подстроку